# Unity & Android: конфликт работы tap и swipe. Не получается реализовать правильный tap

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Я делаю игру под `Android` устройства на `Unity`. 
Есть два скрипта которые управляют свайпом (свайп работает нормально).
Как мне реализовать нажатие? Я пробовал по разному, но когда я свайпаю - ВСЕГДА выполняется `TAP`, а мне нужно чтобы при свайпе не выполнялся `TAP`, потому что при `TAP` выполняется один функционал, а при свайпе - другой.

**Swipe:**

```
public class Swipe : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool tap, swipeLeft, swipeRight, swipeUp, swipeDown;
    private bool isDraging = false;
    private Vector2 startTouch, swipeDelta;

    private void Update()
    {
        tap = swipeLeft = swipeRight = swipeUp = swipeDown = false;

        #region Standalone Inputs
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            tap = true;
            isDraging = true;
            startTouch = Input.mousePosition;
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            isDraging = false;
            Reset();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Mobile Inputs
        if (Input.touches.Length > 0)
        {
            if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                tap = true;
                isDraging = true;
                startTouch = Input.touches[0].position;
            }
            else if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Ended || Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Canceled)
            {
                isDraging = false;
                Reset();
            }
        }
        #endregion

        //Calculate  the distance
        swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
        if (isDraging)
        {
            if (Input.touches.Length > 0)
            {
                swipeDelta = Input.touches[0].position - startTouch;
            }
            else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {
                swipeDelta = (Vector2)Input.mousePosition - startTouch;
            }
        }

        //Did we cross the deadzone?
        if (swipeDelta.magnitude > 5)
        {
                //Which direction ? 
                float x = swipeDelta.x;
                float y = swipeDelta.y;

                if (Mathf.Abs(x) > Mathf.Abs(y))
                {
                    //Left or right
                    if (x < 0)
                        swipeLeft = true;
                    else
                        swipeRight = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (y < 0)
                    {
                        swipeUp = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        swipeDown = true;
                    }
                }
                Reset();
            }

    }


private void Reset()
{
    startTouch = swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
    isDraging = false;
}

public Vector2 SwipeDelta { get { return swipeDelta; } }
public bool SwipeLeft { get { return swipeLeft; } }
public bool SwipeRight { get { return swipeRight; } }
public bool SwipeUp { get { return swipeUp; } }
public bool SwipeDown { get { return swipeDown; } }
}
```

**PlayerController:**

```
void Update()
{

    if (swipeControls.SwipeLeft)
        desiredPosition += Vector3.left * 2.6f;

    if (swipeControls.SwipeRight)
        desiredPosition += Vector3.right * 2.6f;


    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, desiredPosition, 12f * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я добавил проверку:

```
if (tapPosition == Input.touches[0].position) выполнение кода из тэпа
```

Всё теперь работает